# Translate a sum(...) to numpy

Tags: numpy

I would like to do `sum(ai*np.exp(bi*r2) for ai,bi in zip(a,b))` entirely in numpy, where `a` and `b` are 1d arrays, and `r2` can be any shape and the result has the shape of `r2`. My broadcasting-fu is too weak!

Comment: and a for loop over r2 is not an option? Not sure what you mean with entirely in numpy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  np.sum(a*np.exp(b*r2[...,None], axis=-1)
```

The idea is to broadcast with the a,b dimension at the end.

Comment: None being numpy.newaxis, right?

Comment: yes.  `np.newaxis` is clearer for new users; `None` is the samething, that older lazy posters use :)